# Wordpress Ajax call not working when logged in as an Admin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to  make ajax calls work in wordpress.
Code works if I you are logged-out, but the moment you log-in code stops working and throws Error.
So can anybody tell me where the problem is?

Error 400 (Bad Request)

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/wp-ajax/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
S.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:2
fetch @ (index):98
onclick @ (index):107
```

functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'ajax-script',
     get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', 
     array ( 'jquery' ), 
     1.1, 
     true
);

wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-script',
    'my_ajax_obj',
    array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
         'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'title_example' ),
    )
);



add_action('wp-ajax_my_action', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>10));
    if($the_query->have_posts()):
        while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><i><?php the_excerpt(); ?></i></p><hr>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    die();
}
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fetch() {
    // jQuery("#datafetch").html("<h2>"+my_ajax_obj.ajax_url+" </h2>");

    jQuery.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {'action': 'my_action'}, function(response) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').append(response);
    });

}

</script>

<div id="datafetch">
    <button onclick="fetch()">Įkelti įrašus</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `wp-ajax` to `wp_ajax` in
`add_action('wp-ajax_my_action', 'data_fetch');`